# Unable to deploy application on Payara 4.1

Tags: java, primefaces, glassfish, payara

I am trying to deploy my web application on my Payara 4.1 server. However I am getting the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.Application.addSearchKeywordResolver(Ljavax/faces/component/search/SearchKeywordResolver;)V`

When I google this issue, I find a few people with the same problem, however they were all using outdated versions of `Primefaces`, but I am using the latest version (6.2) as you can see in the full logs below.

I've deployed my application before but I changed too much at one time so I don't know what triggered this error. However I did not change any of the library's/dependency's as for as I am aware.

If you need more information, let me know.

[Full logs can be found here](https://pastebin.com/EsEukGUV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually deployed my application on a Glassfish 5 server and it worked again, I have no idea why though.